# Headset causes RF interference

Tags: audio, keyboard, mouse, interference, infrared

Excuse me for not knowing too much about this subject. For months, I've had a wireless mouse and keyboard. It is both RF. One week ago I bought a new wireless headset, and I think it is interfering. Every time I am near my keyboard with my headset, and sometimes random, my keyboard just stops working. I think that they might be on the same frequency, although that chance should be small. Any idea why my keyboard stops working or how I can fix this? Any idea how I can find out which frequency they are on? I have tried to blame the batteries, but after buying new ones and using 4 different pairs, it all failed.

Mouse: [Trust Evo](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00LELMK20) 
Keyboard: [Rapoo 9060 desktopset](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0072NUWNI) (got rid of the mouse) 
Headset: [Logitech G933](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0148NPJ78)

Comment: Just turn it off for a while and see if the problem goes away? As they are probably both using Bluetooth the chance aren't all that slim that they're working on the same frequency but Bluetooth does have mechanisms to handle it. If your neighbor has a damaged microwave it could be more of a problem.

Comment: @Seth It is all radio waves, there is no Bluetooth. When I am not using the headset (off), the keyboard just works fine.

Comment: Well the 2.4 GHz band is indeed free. So assuming they're not using Bluetooth you would either have to ask the vendor/look into the documentation to find details on how they work or use something like a RF Spectrum Analyzer to get those details (quite expensive). If you do know the problem only exists if you have both devices on it's pretty likely that there is some form of side effects between those two. As it's unlikely that you will be able to change the frequency they're operating on it would probably the cheaper to replace either of those components or switch either of them to cable.

Comment: The link you gave mentions "Play lag-free on 2.4 GHz wireless", so whatever protocol it is using, it's in the same band as bluetooth and WLAN. And yes, they can interfere with each other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this issue by letting the receiver be like 10cm away from the device